# Why are my images displaying as grey squares?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm writing a script in Python for my image processing class, which should read a directory for images, display them, and then I will eventually add additional code to perform Otsu thresholding on these images. I can get a reference image to display properly to include Otsu thresholding; however, I run into trouble when I attempt to display the remaining images in the directory. I am not sure that my images are being read from the directory correctly, as I am trying to store them in an array; however, I can see the output window displays grey squares which correspond to the dimensions of the actual image resolutions, which suggests that they are being at least partly read correctly.

I've already attempted to isolate the script to load images and display them into a separate file and running it. I was concerned that the successful processing of my sample image (which included a black/white binarization) was somehow affecting my image display later. This was not the case, as running a separate script produced the same grey square output.

****Update****

I've managed to tweak the below script(not yet updated) to run almost correctly. By writing the full filepath directly for each file, I can get the output to display correctly. It appears there is some issue with loading images into an array, best I can tell; a potential workaround for future testing is importing file locations as a string array, and implementing that vs. loading images into an array directly.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
import time

image=cv.imread('Fig ref.jpg')

image2=cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
cv.imshow('Image', image)
# global thresholding
ret1,th1 = cv.threshold(image2,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,th2 = cv.threshold(image2,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(image2,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv.threshold(blur,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
# plot all the images and their histograms
images = [image2, 0, th1,
          image2, 0, th2,
          blur, 0, th3]
titles = ['Original Noisy Image','Histogram','Global Thresholding     (v=127)',
      'Original Noisy Image','Histogram',"Otsu's Thresholding",
      'Gaussian filtered Image','Histogram',"Otsu's Thresholding"]
for i in range(3):
    plot.subplot(3,3,i*3+1),plot.imshow(images[i*3],'gray')
    plot.title(titles[i*3]), plot.xticks([]), plot.yticks([])
    plot.subplot(3,3,i*3+2),plot.hist(images[i*3].ravel(),256)
    plot.title(titles[i*3+1]), plot.xticks([]), plot.yticks([])
    plot.subplot(3,3,i*3+3),plot.imshow(images[i*3+2],'gray')
    plot.title(titles[i*3+2]), plot.xticks([]), plot.yticks([])
plot.show()

imageFolderPath = 'D:\Google Drive\Engineering\Senior Year\Image     processing\Image processing group work'
imagePath = glob.glob(imageFolderPath + '/*.JPG') 

im_array = np.array( [np.array(Image.open(img).convert('RGB')) for img in imagePath] )
temp=cv.imread("D:\Google Drive\Engineering\Senior Year\Image processing\Image processing group work\Fig ref.jpg")


cv.imshow('image', temp)
time.sleep(15)

for i in range(9):
    cv.imshow('Image', im_array[i])


    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`plot.subplot(3,3,i*3+3),plot.imshow(images[i*3+2],'gray')`: The second argument says you use `gray` color map. Get rid of it and you would get color displays.

Comment: shouldn't that just be for greyscale vs color? My issue is that the only thing that shows is solid grey, not even an image in grey. I'll test it soon, thanks!